# Is there a way to accept only alphabets as input and not numbers? If numbers are given it should show a validation error as it takes only alphabets

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

I'm creating a form where I give certain fields. 
For now, an input field with type text.

I have tried giving validation **" required "** but that is not what I am searching for. If a user gives a number as input, it should validate that it takes only alphabets.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Can you help me how can I do this on the go while typing inside the textfield and validate if a number is given

Comment: Take a read of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do validation using pattern like this.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

or validation can be done by Jquery. input fields will not accept any other input except alphabets.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
               First name <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
               Last name <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
                <script>
                    $( document ).ready(function() {
                        $( "#fname" ).keypress(function(e) {
                            var key = e.keyCode;
                            if (key >= 48 && key <= 57) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                            }
                        });
                        $( "#lname" ).keypress(function(e) {
                            var key = e.keyCode;
                             if (key >= 48 && key <= 57) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                            }
                         });
                    });
                </script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Note that this is all client side. People can easily remove this and submit numbers. So if your backend is expecting a string without any numbers you need to do the validation in php as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try the snippet below:

```
if (!/^([^0-9]*)$/.test($(input).val())) {
  alert("This only accepts alphabets!");
}
else
{
  //submit
}
```

The idea is to use regex to validate the input value then just alert to notify the client.

An alternative way is to disable numbers immediately on keypress.

```
    $("input").keypress(function (e) {
    if (!/^([^0-9]*)$/.test(e.key)) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pattern

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The pattern attribute specifies a regular expression that the  element's value is checked against on form submission.

Comment: thank you. I was actually looking for the same but a little bit different. Like, I wanted to show the validation while typing itself, or when we go to the next field it should alert that only alphabets should be given and not numbers.